# Load all payment methods in system config

Tags: payment-methods, admin-panel, magento-1.14, system-config

I want to load all available payment methods in a multiselect system config in admin. Could some one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In system.xml

,

```
<test translate="label">
      <label>Available Payments</label>
      <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
      <source_model>module_name/system_config_source_payment</source_model>
      <sort_order>5</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</test>
```

> In Namespace/Modulename/Model/System/Config/Source/Payment.php

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_System_Config_Source_Payment
{
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
           $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();

           //$methods = array(array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('--Please Select--')));

           foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
                $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
                $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                    'label'   => $paymentTitle,
                    'value' => $paymentCode,
                );
            }
            return $methods;
        }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore , there is issue near foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {, specifically with $paymentCode

Comment: Works fine for me... no issue near foreach...

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement on above answer - makes solution store specific.

```
 class Namespace_Module_Model_System_Config_Source_Payment
 {
   public function toOptionArray()
   {
    //need to workout which store we are on
    $methods = [];
    $currentStoreId = null;

    /* Get current configuration store code */
    if(strlen($currentStoreCode = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getStore())){
        $currentStoreId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($currentStoreCode)->getId();
    }

    $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods($currentStoreId);

    foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
        $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
        $paymentTitle .= ' ('.$paymentCode.')';
        $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
            'label'   => $paymentTitle,
            'value' => $paymentCode,
        );
    }
    return $methods;
}
```